# CSS transition for a background-image on hover?

Tags: html, css, joomla, css-transitions

I am working on webpage where I want to use background image on hover effect, however I have some issue. Image is display on hover with tranisiton but when I move back my mouse then transition is not working and it is not looking good - there is no hover out effect, I hope it is clear. I would like to also use scall effect for hover but I don't have additional wrapar as content is generated by additional module in joomla.

I tried also implement solution with opacity but then I am loosing my border as I don't have additional wrapper.

So far this is my code on website test3.reksio.net

```
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1):hover
{
background-image: url("https://danielhagnoul.developpez.com/images/boule1.png");
transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: transition needs to be on the main selector, without the :hover otherwise it won't be applied when you hover but only when you leave

Comment: can you put code of your idea,pls

Comment: I added it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```css
div{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
div:before{
  content:'';
  transition: all 0.7s; 
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("https://danielhagnoul.developpez.com/images/boule1.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1;
}

div:hover:before{
  opacity: 0;
}

div:hover span{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1111</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it is almost what I am looking for, but opacity is in opposite way. Background need to show on hover and not disappear on hover. I changed that but I have problem with margin and span... could you please look on my site? https://test3.reksio.net

Comment: Margin is fixed but my span in not visible on hover :(

Comment: any ideas what to change to show text after hover?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1):hover
{
background-image: url("https://danielhagnoul.developpez.com/images/boule1.png");
transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I tried that also and it is not working for me.. maybe something else overwrite this code not sure... not event why this transition is in from left side :(

Comment: update your code and add HTML code, and let me know exactly what you wanna achieve

Comment: I want to achive something similar like here on main tile with news miodowa.edu.pl, my template is generated from TemplateToaster tool,

Comment: what it the code without the hover?

Comment: Only margin, border and padding, you check on website https://test3.reksio.net div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
{
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 45px;
}

Comment: I added white image background for non hover div and then it looks like I want, but it shouldn't be done in that way

Comment: I would like to have normal linear fade effect but I have some stretch effect

Comment: did you try transparent background? and for transition make it : transition: background 0.7s ease-in-out

Comment: yes I did without success :/

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the transition appear both upon hovering and leaving the element, apply said transition to the element itself; for example, using your css rules in the question it would look like this:

```
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
{
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
}

div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1):hover
{
    background-image: url("https://danielhagnoul.developpez.com/images/boule1.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I never tried animating a background image like this. Since the background image is loaded only on hover, the first time there will be a delay (if it's not loaded somewhere else on the page).  I would advise you to load the image in the normal style, and "hide" it with `background-position` or `background-size` i.e.

```
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
{
    transition: background-size 0.7s ease-in;
    background-image: url("https://danielhagnoul.developpez.com/images/boule1.png");
    background-size: 0 0;
}

div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1):hover
{        
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately is not working, hover effect is smooth but there is no transition out, when you move back your mouse. You can check on site, 2nd row center box

Comment: it seems like the transition is on the `.col-lg`, try changing the rule to `transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out`